# Hi, I have one question regarding cloning of profile,

Tags: profile, administration, custom-profile

Is it possible to clone a profile and change its license? We need to change a profile's license.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, but it's not very user-friendly to do so.
You must already know that you can't change your license via UI.

But we can change it via VSCode. You have to follow the below steps.

```
1) Clone a profile and name it for example "Dummy"
2) Retrieve it in VSCode.
3) Now update Dummy.profile-meta.xml to your desired name for example 1Dummy.profile-meta.xml
4) Look for <userLicense> tag in the XML and update it with appropriate license.
5) Deploy
6) A new profile with the name dummy1 is created with the desired license now delete the old profile
```

NOTE: You have to make sure your XML doesn't contain any permissions that are not supported via the desired license, If any unwanted permissions are present it will keep on giving errors while deploying.